# Determining time complexity of for loop?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have loop

```
sum = 0 ;
    for ( i = n ; i > 0; i = i/3 )
        for ( j = 0 ; j < n^3 ; j++ )
              sum++ ;
```

I have to figure out the time complexity in big theta notation, but the i/3 in the first loop is confusing me.

Comment: The outer loop is O(log n). Is that enough to work with?

Comment: I want to say the inner is n^3 which would make it O(nlog(n))?

Comment: I think you'd be better served on https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for the link, this has given me a good handle on in.

Answer (score -1):

In normal math, this loop will never terminate.  O(inf).  In discrete math, it is O(n^3).

The outer loop...

```
for ( i = n ; i > 0; i = i/3 )
```

The loop runs while i is greater than 0.  If i is positive, reducing i by a third will *never* bring i below 0 becoming fractionally smaller and smaller.

If i is an IEEE Floating Point number, it will eventually reach 0 after a lot of iterations depending on the size of your floats.

If the numbers are assumed to be integers (which is what I think you're asking with the discrete-mathematics tag) the outer loop is O(log(n)) as i is cut by a third each iteration and will rapidly reach 0.

The inner loop, standing on its own, is pretty easy to see as O(n^3).

```
for ( my $j = 0; $j < $n**3 ; $j++ ) {
    $sum++;
}
```

An O(n^3) loop inside an O(log(n)) loop is O(n^3 log(n)) which isn't a significantly different growth curve from O(n^3).

Comment: I confess that the idea of `i` *not* being an integer type didn't occur to me. But you're wrong about the complexity of the whole; it's O(n^3 log(n)).

Comment: @Beta I just threw it out as effectively being constant compared to n^3.  You're probably right that's not technically correct, but I don't think it significantly changes the growth curve.